# Selection option "selected" attribute

Tags: php, html-select

I've got an absolute mind blank here. Basically what I've done is created a mini Article Manager. Each article can be assigned to one of the following categories which are defined in a select dropdown.

- Design
- Development
- Other

When I go to edit an article, I have retrieved the data from the database and populated the inputs and textarea.

What I'm now trying to do is apply the `selected` attribute to the option that matches the article category. The following is what I have done, which I'm sure you will agree is a bad approach:

```
<?php if($category == 'Design') {  ?>

    <option value="Design" selected>Design</option>
    <option value="Development">Development</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>

<?php } elseif($category == 'Development') { ?>

    <option value="Design">Design</option> 
    <option value="Development" selected>Development</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>

<?php } else { ?>

    <option value="Design">Design</option>
    <option value="Development">Development</option>
    <option value="Other" selected>Other</option>

<?php } ?>
```

So the question being is, how can I implement a more dynamic method of applying the `selected` attribute to an `<option>` based on the article category?

Comment: heyy i didn't see your reputation... are you serious??

Comment: @FerozAkbar what does his rep have to do with a valid question?

Comment: reputation itself tells somany things bro

Comment: @FerozAkbar - Like I said, having an absolute mind blank :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just define the categories in an array, and loop it:

```
<?php
$cats = array('Design', 'Development', 'Other');
foreach($cats as $cat)
{
    $selected = ($cat == $category) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo '<option value="'.$cat.'"'.$selected.'>'.$cat.'</option>';
}
?>
```

Of course, this has the added benefit that in case you need to add a new category, just add it to the array.

Answer (score 3):

Put the categories in an array, then do something like:

```
$categories = Array("Foo", "Bar", "Baz");
$preselected_category = "Bar";

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $html = htmlspecialchars($category);
    $selected = "";
    if ($category == $preselected_category) {
        $selected = "selected";
    }
    ?> <option value="<?=$html?>" <?=$selected?>> <?=html?> </option> <?php
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use it like below

```
<option value="Design" <?=($category == 'Design')?'selected':''?> >Design</option>
<option value="Development" <?=($category == 'Development')?'selected':''?>>Development</option>
<option value="Other" <?=($category == 'Other')?'selected':''?>>Other</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
<option value="Design" <? if($category == 'Design') { echo 'selected';} ?>>Design</option> 
<option value="Development" <? if($category == 'Development') { echo 'selected';} ?>>Development</option>
<option value="Other" <? if($category == 'Othe') { echo 'selected';} ?>>Other</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to store the categories, and loop through it to generate your html.

---

```
<?php

    $categories = array(
      'Design',
      'Development',
      'Other',
    );

    $category = 'Design';

    foreach($categories as $cat) {
      $selected = ($category == $cat);
      $selcode = ($selected ? ' selected' : '');
      $html = '<option value="'.$cat.'"'.$selcode.'>'.$cat.'</option>';
      echo $html . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Comment: It may be better to upvote answers already posted, rather than duplicating them.

Comment: I didn't realize answers had been posted already -- thank you for the advice.