# PHP combined with HTML code

Tags: php, html

I am trying to put some php code in a code that is combined with HTML.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM klassen");
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<div class="groepitem"><input type="radio" [IN THIS PLACE] name="groep" value="' . $record['klasNaam'] . '">' . $record['klasNaam'] . '</div>';
}
?>
```

On the [in this place] spot I want to put the following code:

```
if($_SESSION['gebruikers_klasid'] == $record['klas_id']) {
echo 'checked';
}
```

I have tried it multiple times but I just can't get it to work.

Comment: Try putting the conditional statement right after your `while` loop, while assigning a variable to it, like `$checked="checked";` then echo/place the variable in the `[in this place]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selection option "selected" attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914779/selection-option-selected-attribute)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can concatenate a ternary operator like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM klassen");
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<div class="groepitem"><input type="radio" ' . ($_SESSION['gebruikers_klasid'] == $record['klas_id'] ? "checked" : "") . ' name="groep" value="' . $record['klasNaam'] . '">' . $record['klasNaam'] . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: All in one go ;) ternaries are so nice to work with.

Comment: It does not seem to work. 
When I add the following code:
($_SESSION['gebruikers_klasid'] == $record['klas_id'] ? "checked": "")

It wont add 'checked'.

When I add: 
if($_SESSION['gebruikers_klasid'] == $record['klas_id']) {
echo 'checked';
}

it DOES add 'checked'.

Comment: @Diederiikk Did you start your session?

Comment: @Diederiikk Now it should work! Forgot to add spaces. Just copy it again and it should work

Comment: @Diederiikk What Rizier meant was, is `session_start();` included inside all pages using sessions?

Comment: Yes it does work! You forgot the '{}' around the while but now it works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM klassen");

while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($_SESSION['gebruikers_klasid'] == $record['klas_id']) {
        $var = 'checked';
    }
    echo '<div class="groepitem"><input type="radio" '.$var.' name="groep" value="' . $record['klasNaam'] . '">' . $record['klasNaam'] . '</div>';
}

?>
```

EDIT: now session check it's inside the loop

Comment: [Just like and similar to what I said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447738/php-combined-with-html-code#comment43334389_27447738) ;) *well interpreted*.

Comment: That won't work; the comparison needs to be in the while loop.

Comment: @Brett Yep, that's why I said "similar" to what I said. It needs to be inside the `while` loop.

Comment: *well interpreted*, well... almost.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this many different ways, but if you want cleaner html code:

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM klassen");

while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    if ($_SESSION['gebruikers_klasid'] == $record['klas_id']) {
        $checked = ' checked';
    } else {
        $checked = '';
    }

    echo '<div class="groepitem"><input type="radio"' . $checked . ' name="groep" value="' . $record['klasNaam'] . '">' . $record['klasNaam'] . '</div>';

}

?>
```

OR...

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM klassen");

while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $checked = ($_SESSION['gebruikers_klasid'] == $record['klas_id']) ? ' checked' : '';

    echo '<div class="groepitem"><input type="radio"' . $checked . ' name="groep" value="' . $record['klasNaam'] . '">' . $record['klasNaam'] . '</div>';

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to exit your echo then run the conditional statement then resume your echo... eg

```
<?php 
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM klassen");   
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo '<div class="groepitem"><input type="radio" '; 
   if($_SESSION['gebruikers_klasid'] == $record['klas_id']) { echo 'checked'; }
    echo ' name="groep" value="' . $record['klasNaam'] . '">' . $record['klasNaam'] . '</div>'; 
} 
?>
```